# The system is running in low graphics mode. How do I fix this?

Tags: upgrade, screen, input-devices

I was updating ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04. Somewhere in between the system restarted and the following message came up:

> The system is running in low graphics mode. Your screen, graphics card, and input device settings couldn't be detected correctly.  You will need to configure these yourself

I went to failsafe recovery following the question "[How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)" but I was unable to open the terminal.

How do I fix it??

Comment: You said "…following the question which has been asked here before…" Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/885185/edit) and add a link to the other question you're referring to.

Comment: Are you using a ati radeon graphics card?

Comment: I think I am using nvidia. Not sure though!! I don't remember.

Answer (score 4):

Your nivdia driver/libraries are possibly conflicting with the newer X11 libraries from the upgrade. Two things to check...  either logging remotely or Ctrl-Alt-F1 so you are in terminal mode.

1 - Make sure Your /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf is in good shape. If you are unsure you can reset to default.

```
sudo rm /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
sudo ucf -p /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm
```

2 - Check your current nvidia drivers

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

Look at the output and determine the *recommended* driver

```
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000DDAsv000017AAsd000021D1bc03sc00i00
model    : GF106GLM [Quadro 2000M]
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
driver   : nvidia-304-updates - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-304 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-331 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-331-updates - distro non-free
```

and follow the output which could be as easy as.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
```

*I myself would recommend you un-install any installed nvidia drivers if any before running ubuntu-drivers to clean out before proceeding.*

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar situation when upgrading my Dell Vostro 1500 (Nvidia 8400M GS) to Ubuntu 16.04.2. There the reason was a wrong proprietary driver version. In particular, the `nvidia-304` which used to work fine before needed to be replaced with the newer `nvidia-340`.

First find out which driver number you need. Enter your card details on the [Nvidia Download page](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us), select Linux and click "Search". It gives you the current nvidia driver number like e.g. `340.102`. The first number is the number you're looking for, in this example it would be 340.

As described above press CTRL+ALT+F1 to get to the text console. Then log in and install the proper driver (use the number you got above) via:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-340
```

Now you're almost done, however there is one more **important thing**. If your previous driver (in my case `nvidia-304`) was using `bumblebee` and the new driver isn't, you will likely end-up in another pitfall - the **infinite login loop**. Therefore you need to check one more thing:

Check if `bumblebee` is installed:

```
apt list --installed | grep bumblebee
```

If not (empty answer from the command) make sure to delete any residual bumblebee module blacklist, which breaks the new driver and causes the infinite login loop:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf
```

After this your graphics should work. Either reboot or restart lightdm by

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by upgrading the Linux kernel:

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to enter terminal
2. Upgrade kernel with `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04` (This is for ubuntu 16.04 desktop, for server see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).